# Replace files in subfolders if exist using batch or shell

Tags: powershell, shell, batch-file, powershell-2.0

I have a source folder with 10-80 files jpg images

I need to copy them into a destination folder with subfolders and replace each existing files with its version from the source folder BUT only when such file is already present there

If there is not such files there do not place a copy

Can I do that with batch or shell? And what is better and faster?

Comment: `xcopy /?` - especially the  `/U` switch.

Comment: @Stephan thank you for help, it did replaced the files, but only in the folder's root, not in subfolders, so how can i search for the files in destination folder with subfolders and replace them if existe?

Comment: `xcopy /?` - especially the `/S` switch.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell can make quick work of this.  Assuming the photos have the same name in the source and destination, this should work.

```
# Get the source photos
$SourcePhotos = Get-ChildItem -Path '.\Source'

# Loop through each of our source photos
foreach ($SourcePhoto in $SourcePhotos) {
    # Recuresively search the destination for the photo from the source
    $DestinationPhoto = Get-ChildItem -Path '.\Destination' -Filter $SourcePhoto.Name -Recurse
    # If we find the photo in the destination...
    if ($DestinationPhoto) {
        # Copy from source to destination forcefully to overwrite the one at the destination
        Copy-Item $SourcePhoto.FullName $DestinationPhoto.FullName -Force
    }
}
```

Comment: i test it, didn't worked, nothing happend, with two folders Source and Destination

Comment: @MohamedJawadi please give the structure of your directories and i can fine-tune the script